# Is using .after() an inefficient method compare to just put markup on the page?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have this markup that I'd like to use to for a dialog.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Empty Alert Message">Alert message cannot be empty.</div>
```

I have 2 solutions:

1. add it somewhere, let's say at the end of the page
2. use `.after()` to append it to an existing element

Then apply `$('#dialog').dialog()` to that element.

I'm hearing that's modifying the DOM is a very bad practice because the DOM will be modified and needs to be re-created. that's really inefficient.

Is that true? I'm not an expert in JavaScript. I didn't know that little thing would slow the whole execution down.

Thanks for helping

Comment: If you're doing it less than a thousand times, it doesn't matter. Modern browsers are fast.

Comment: You can always test it and see if it make a difference. Personally, I prefer to hide text in the document or get it with Ajax rather than put text in a js file.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: So it's just a matter of preferences? No significant performance difference?

Comment: Is your question specific to jQuery UI?

Comment: @Richard77 Well mixing content with code is never a good idea if it can be avoided, so it's not just a preference, but as far as performance is concerned, just try it, you won't see any difference in the page display unless you use that in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding markup by doing something like:

```
obj.innerHTML += newHTML;
```

is indeed bad as it recreates all the objects in the obj hierarchy and trashes all event handlers in that hierarchy.

But, programmatically adding DOM elements with functions like `.after()` is perfectly fine as it just adds the new elements and doesn't disturb any existing objects.

One other aspect that takes time in manipulating the DOM is doing layout.  When you add new objects to the DOM they have to be factored into the layout of the page and then it all has to be repainted.  If once is doing many sequential DOM operations, this can significantly slow down your operation.  But, in both of your cases, you're going to be making the dialog visible once (presuming it was `display: none` if already in the HTML of your page) so it's going to be laid out and displayed much the same either way.

In your two cases, either method would be fine - there would be no noticeable performance difference.  The advantage of having all the markup in the original page is that you can manage it all in once place more easily and won't have content mixed in with your javascript.  If you have hundreds of differently possible dialogs, then you might not want them all to be in the main page.

Comment: Adding the element doesn't disturb the DOM structure, but it forces the browser to rebuild the layout. I am assuming it is a non issue here because the dialog will actually be hidden (display none).

Comment: @Christophe - I added to my answer on that topic.